# Extract a String with T-SQL

Tags: string, t-sql, substring

I need to extract the  City and State location (e.g. location=Winnetka, IL) from a string.

Here is an example of a very long string, and notice the substring
"location=Winnetka, IL, url" in the long string. I want `Winnetka, IL` to be my result.

> 73667117890441200, id_str=973667117890441216, name=PriceTarget Research Inc, screen_name=prctarget, location=Winnetka, IL, url=http://pricetargetresearch.com, description=Combining valuation and timeliness ranks with deep fundamentals, PriceTarget Research publishes Value Trend stock ratings, research, and alerts on 6,000 stocks., translator_type=none, protected=false, verified=false, followers_count=7, friends_count=0, listed_count=0, favourites_count=0

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? You might transfer this to a JSON string... (needs v2016+). But there is a big flaw in it: The delimiter is the comma, but you have got several commas within values. You can find where to start easily, but not where to end. What would happen, if your description contains a `=`? If this format is under your control you really should change this... (XML, JSON or quoted CSV). With other tools you might use `RegEx` to find `, SomeName=` with a variable `SomeName`...

Answer (score 0):

As variant you can try to use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` functions to achieve it:

```
DECLARE
  @loc_len int=LEN('location='),
  @txt nvarchar(1000)='73667117890441200, id_str=973667117890441216, name=PriceTarget Research Inc, screen_name=prctarget, location=Winnetka, IL, url=http://pricetargetresearch.com, description=Combining valuation and timeliness ranks with deep fundamentals, PriceTarget Research publishes Value Trend stock ratings, research, and alerts on 6,000 stocks., translator_type=none, protected=false, verified=false, followers_count=7, friends_count=0, listed_count=0, favourites_count=0'

SELECT
  SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('location=',txt)+@loc_len,CHARINDEX(', url=',txt)-CHARINDEX('location=',txt)-@loc_len)
FROM
  (
    SELECT @txt txt -- your query is here
  ) q
```

You also can use variables for markers:

```
DECLARE
  @txt nvarchar(1000)='73667117890441200, id_str=973667117890441216, name=PriceTarget Research Inc, screen_name=prctarget, location=Winnetka, IL, url=http://pricetargetresearch.com, description=Combining valuation and timeliness ranks with deep fundamentals, PriceTarget Research publishes Value Trend stock ratings, research, and alerts on 6,000 stocks., translator_type=none, protected=false, verified=false, followers_count=7, friends_count=0, listed_count=0, favourites_count=0'

-- markers
DECLARE
  @mark1 varchar(20)='location=',
  @mark2 varchar(20)=', url='

-- start marker len
DECLARE @loc_len int=LEN(@mark1)

SELECT
  SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX(@mark1,txt)+@loc_len,CHARINDEX(@mark2,txt)-CHARINDEX(@mark1,txt)-@loc_len)
FROM
  (
    SELECT @txt txt -- your query is here
  ) q
```

Comment: This works fine. Better to use the LEN function than hard coded valure

Comment: Ok. Then you can use a variable. I think it'll be better - isn't so long and is faster. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case the next tag is not ', url=', we need to search for the equal sign and back up to the space.  Here are the primitives that could be used to put together a solution.

```
declare @inputStr varchar(500) = '73667117890441200, id_str=973667117890441216, name=PriceTarget Research Inc, screen_name=prctarget, location=Winnetka, IL, url=http://pricetargetresearch.com, description=Combining valuation and timeliness ranks with deep fundamentals, PriceTarget Research publishes Value Trend stock ratings, research, and alerts on 6,000 stocks., translator_type=none, protected=false, verified=false, followers_count=7, friends_count=0, listed_count=0, favourites_count=0';

declare @posLocation integer, @posCityState integer, @posNextEq integer
declare @valCityStateAndNextTag varchar(500), @justCityState varchar(500)

Select @posLocation = charindex('location=', @inputStr);
Select @posCityState = @posLocation + LEN('location=');
Select @posNextEq = CHARINDEX('=', @inputStr,@posCityState+2);
print (@posCityState);
print (@posNextEq);

Select @valCityStateAndNextTag = SUBSTRING(@inputStr, @posCityState, @posNextEq - @posCityState);
print (@valCityStateAndNextTag) ;

select  @justCityState = left(@valCityStateAndNextTag, len(@valCityStateAndNextTag) - charindex(' ', reverse(@valCityStateAndNextTag) ) - 1);
print (@justCityState)
```

Results are--

```
110
127
Winnetka, IL, url
Winnetka, IL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` you can get the expected output:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@PrintData, 
                 CHARINDEX('location=', @PrintData) + LEN('location='), 
                 CHARINDEX(', url=', @PrintData, CHARINDEX('location=', @PrintData)) - (CHARINDEX('location=', @PrintData) + LEN('location='))
                 );
```

Comment: @PeterAkwichek If it solves your problem, can you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043), so that others know the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This will be similar to the solution @Arulkumar put together but using a [Cascading (CROSS) APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-cascading-cross-apply-2) to make the code cleaner and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)er.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = '73667117890441200, id_str=973667117890441216, name=PriceTarget Research Inc, screen_name=prctarget, location=Winnetka, IL, url=http://pricetargetresearch.com, description=Combining valuation and timeliness ranks with deep fundamentals, PriceTarget Research publishes Value Trend stock ratings, research, and alerts on 6,000 stocks., translator_type=none, protected=false, verified=false, followers_count=7, friends_count=0, listed_count=0, favourites_count=0';

SELECT      NewString = SUBSTRING(@string,p0.Pos,p2.Pos-p0.Pos)
FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX('location=',@string)+9)) AS p0(Pos) -- text starts here
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',@string,p0.Pos)+1))  AS p1(Pos) -- 1st comma after p0
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',@string,p1.Pos)))    AS p2(Pos); -- 2nd  comma after p1

DECLARE @table TABLE (stringId INT IDENTITY, string VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @table(string) VALUES (@string),(REPLACE(@string,'Winnetka','Chicago'));
```

**Against a table**

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = '73667117890441200, id_str=973667117890441216, name=PriceTarget Research Inc, screen_name=prctarget, location=Winnetka, IL, url=http://pricetargetresearch.com, description=Combining valuation and timeliness ranks with deep fundamentals, PriceTarget Research publishes Value Trend stock ratings, research, and alerts on 6,000 stocks., translator_type=none, protected=false, verified=false, followers_count=7, friends_count=0, listed_count=0, favourites_count=0';    
DECLARE @table TABLE (stringId INT IDENTITY, string VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @table(string) VALUES (@string),(REPLACE(@string,'Winnetka','Chicago'));

SELECT t.stringId, f.NewString
FROM   @table AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT      NewString = SUBSTRING(t.string,p0.Pos,p2.Pos-p0.Pos)
  FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX('location=',t.string)+9)) AS p0(Pos) -- text starts here
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',t.string,p0.Pos)+1))  AS p1(Pos) -- 1st comma after p0
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',t.string,p1.Pos)))    AS p2(Pos) -- 2nd  comma after p1
) AS f;
```